# Date counts to be display in specific conditions in the stored proc like [0-6 days],[7-14 days] etc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am creating a ssrs report and SP. so i have requirement like this below.
I have table called management in that we have a column description so the data under the
description are only 'Open' and 'Closed'.

I have parameter called User, Start Date and End Date

I need to display the user who all have the count of open cases which are falls under between the start date and
end date in the below conditions.
The conditions are
0-5 days
6-11 days
12-18 days.

For ex:
If i enter start date(MM/DD/YYYY) as 12-1-2019 and end date as 12-31-2019
So i need to display users who has the open case count between the 0-5 days,6-11 days and 12-18 days.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you, along with your attempts.

Comment: I have data like this below
1)I have to display the users who has open cases under the specified days conditions as
mentioned above
User
user1 etc
2)I have a table management and in that under Description column i have data as like below
Description
-----------
Open
closed
Open
Open
Closed
Expected results as
if chose 2019-12-01 as sd and 2019-12-31                                                          i may get a user whose date under 0-6 days and then we need to display it as count 1 under 0-6 days(Open)user  0-5days 6-11days
user1 2 1 
user2  1 2

Comment: Data is complete doesn't help. Put **consumable** data in your question.

Comment: Actually i want like below
User   0-5days  6-11days  12-18days
----   ------- -------   -------
User1    2   1    3
User2  1   4    2
User3  5   0    1
Explanation: User 1 has 2 open cases between 0-5 days means when i enter date range consider
2019-01-01 and 2019-31-01 so i have 2 open cases between first 0-5 days(2019-01-01 and 
2019-05-01) and 1 open cases between next 6-11 days(2019-06-01 and 2019-11-01) etc.
Can i get like this?

Answer (score 0):

how about something like that?

```
select   [0-5] = SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF(day,OpenDate, CloseDate) >= 0 and DATEDIFF(day,OpenDate, CloseDate) <= 5,1,0))
        ,[6-11] = SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF(day,OpenDate, CloseDate) >= 6 and DATEDIFF(day,OpenDate, CloseDate) <= 11,1,0))
        ,[12-18] = SUM(IIF(DATEDIFF(day,OpenDate, CloseDate) >= 12 and DATEDIFF(day,OpenDate, CloseDate) <= 18,1,0))
from tblOpenClose
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of conditional aggregation.
Combined with a Cross Apply for the ranges.

```
SELECT t.UserId, a.DateDiffRange
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Description LIKE 'Open%' THEN 1 END) AS [Open]
, COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Description LIKE 'Closed%' THEN 1 END) AS [Closed]
, COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM management AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 
  (CASE 
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, t.[Start Date], t.[End Date]) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN '00-05'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, t.[Start Date], t.[End Date]) BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN '06-11'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, t.[Start Date], t.[End Date]) BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN '12-18'
   WHEN DATEDIFF(day, t.[Start Date], t.[End Date]) BETWEEN 19 AND 30 THEN '19-30'
   END) AS DateDiffRange
) AS a
WHERE t.[Start Date] >= CAST('2019-12-01' AS DATE)
  AND t.[End Date] BETWEEN t.[Start Date] AND EOMONTH(t.[Start Date])
GROUP BY YEAR(t.[Start Date]), MONTH(t.[Start Date]), t.UserId, a.DateDiffRange
ORDER BY t.UserId, a.DateDiffRange;
```

And for more metrics per user?
Check this out for inspiration:

```
SELECT (YEAR(t.[Start Date])*100+MONTH(t.[Start Date])) AS YearMonth, t.UserId
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Within 0-5]
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Within 6-11]
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Within 12-18]
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 19 AND 30 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Within 19-30]

, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 0 AND 5 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Within 0-5]
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Within 6-11]
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Within 12-18]
, SUM(CASE WHEN a.DateDiff BETWEEN 19 AND 30 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Within 19-30]

, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Start 1-5]
, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Start 6-11]
, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Start 12-18]
, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 19 AND 30 THEN a.IsOpen END) AS [Opened Start 19-31]

, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Start 0-5]
, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 6 AND 11 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Start 6-11]
, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 12 AND 18 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Start 12-18]
, SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(t.[Start Date]) BETWEEN 19 AND 31 THEN a.IsClosed END) AS [Closed Start 19-31]

, COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM management AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(day, t.[Start Date], t.[End Date]) AS [DateDiff],
  CASE WHEN t.Description LIKE 'Open%' THEN 1 END AS [IsOpen],
  CASE WHEN t.Description LIKE 'Closed%' THEN 1 END AS [IsClosed]
) AS a
WHERE t.[Start Date] >= CAST('2019-12-01' AS DATE)
  AND t.[End Date] BETWEEN t.[Start Date] AND EOMONTH(t.[Start Date])
GROUP BY YEAR(t.[Start Date]), MONTH(t.[Start Date]), t.UserId
ORDER BY YearMonth, t.UserId;
```

> ```
> YearMonth | UserId | Opened Within 0-5 | Opened Within 6-11 | Opened Within 12-18 | Opened Within 19-30 | Closed Within 0-5 | Closed Within 6-11 | Closed Within 12-18 | Closed Within 19-30 | Opened Start 1-5 | Opened Start 6-11 | Opened Start 12-18 | Opened Start 19-31 | Closed Start 0-5 | Closed Start 6-11 | Closed Start 12-18 | Closed Start 19-31 | Total
> --------: | -----: | ----------------: | -----------------: | ------------------: | ------------------: | ----------------: | -----------------: | ------------------: | ------------------: | ---------------: | ----------------: | -----------------: | -----------------: | ---------------: | ----------------: | -----------------: | -----------------: | ----:
>    201912 |    101 |                 4 |                  4 |                   3 |                   1 |              null |                  1 |                   3 |                   1 |               10 |              null |                  2 |               null |                5 |              null |               null |               null |    17
>    201912 |    102 |                 3 |                  2 |                null |                null |              null |               null |                null |                null |                5 |              null |               null |               null |             null |              null |               null |               null |     5
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d625f8e230be096e2a08361bd5607154)*

Comment: Hi LukStorms,
Actually thats correct answer but can i get it like below
User   0-5days  6-11days  12-18days
------      -------   -------       -------
User1       2    1                 3
User2  1    4                 2
User3  5    0                 1
Explanation: User 1 has 2 open cases between 0-5 days means when i enter date range consider
2019-01-01 and 2019-31-01 so i have 2 open cases between first 0-5 days(2019-01-01 and 
2019-05-01) and 1 open cases between next 6-11 days(2019-06-01 and 2019-11-01) etc. for user1 like that for user2 and user3.
Can i get like this?